# Enable TSlint ordered-imports rule with module-source-path

Tags: typescript, webstorm, tslint

I'm trying to configure my TSLint rules to include: `ordered-imports` with `module-source-path`. I want to have rules where imports are ordered first by path and then sources with separate groups (1grp = external libs, 2grp = internal sources). Auto-fix is also important to me.

Example of correctly sorted imports:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { MainComponent } from 'app/components/main.component';
import { MainService } from 'app/services/main.service';
```

I added this to my `tslint.json`:

```
"ordered-imports": [
        true,
        {
            "import-sources-order": "any",
            "named-imports-order": "case-insensitive",
            "grouped-imports": true,
            "module-source-path": "full"
        }
    ],
```

and my WebStorm throws error/warning on lines `"grouped-imports": true,` and `"module-source-path": "full"` saying "Property 'X' is not allowed" (where X is one of these options). According to docs https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/ordered-imports/ its possible to add it.

What is also interesting there are only 3 out of 4 options for this rule on [GitHub](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/test/rules/ordered-imports/grouped-imports/tslint.json)

Using: **TSLint 5.11.0** and **WebStorm 2018.2.2**.

Am I doing something wrong? is there other way to apply these rules?

**EDIT:** btw warning are one thing, other thing is that these 2 rules doesn't work at all - linter not calling error with imports like this:

```
import { MainService } from 'app/services/main.service';
import { MainComponent } from 'app/components/main.component';
```

Answer (score 3):

Options are valid; the problem is that the bundled tslint JSON schema file is validated against is not up-to-date.
Logged as [WEB-34689](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34689), please follow it for updates.
For now I can only suggest disabling **Compliance with JSON schema** inspection in **Settings | Editor | InspectionsJSON and JSON5** to suppress the errors

Comment: thank you for reporting it, but warnings are not the only problem here, these 2 rules doesn't work, I edited my question with example

Comment: are you using path mappings? Can be https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3654. Anyway, please submit an issue to https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues, providing the project issue can be recreated with